# Storing variables of GameObjects into Array [Unity]

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have 3 kinds of GameObject, namely blueBook, redBook and greenBook. There are 2 blueBook, 7 redBook and 4 greenBook in the scene.

They are each assigned with the following example script that have 3 properties.

```
public class blueBook : MonoBehaviour {

    public string type = "BlueBook";
    public string colour = "Blue";
    public float weight;
    float s;

    void Start () {
        float weightValue;
        weightValue = Random.value;
        weight = Mathf.RoundToInt (700*weightValue+300);
        s=weight/1000; //s is scale ratio 
        transform.localScale += new Vector3(s,s,s);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }
}
```

In the new class, I want to take all the variables of the GameObject (type, colour, weight) and store them inside an array. How to do this?

After they are all stored inside the array, user will input an weight. Then another class will search through all the info to delete both the array and GameObject(in the scene) with the same amount of weight.

Thank you.

---

UPDATE

---

blueBook.cs

```
public class blueBook: MonoBehaviour {

public string type = "blueBook";
public string colour = "Red";
public float weight;
float s;

void Start () {
    float weightValue;
    weightValue = Random.value;
    weight = Mathf.RoundToInt (500*weightValue+100);
    s=weight/1000; //s is scale ratio 
    transform.localScale += new Vector3(s,s,s);
    Debug.Log(weight);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}
```

}

block.cs

```
public class block: MonoBehaviour{

public List<GameObject> players;

    void Start()
    {   Debug.Log(players[1].GetComponent<blueBoook>().weight);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
```

The debug.log for block.cs displayed 0 everytime eventho it display otherwise in debug.log of bluebook.cs. It is because it displayed the initial number? I don know wat is wrong

Comment: If the user inputs only weight, there would be no need for the other two properties to be stored? Or was that just an example and the user could insert either of the three? I would suggest building a dictionary with weight being the key and gameobject or rather a list of gameobjects the value: `Dictionary<float, List<GameObject> >`. You need something that gets all the objects (e.g. public arrays + inspector or finding via tag), that sorts those into the dictionary (if there is a key of that weight, append the list, otherwise create a new entry).

Comment: The variables are in the script. so each already have their own variable. user input will only delete the item and nothing else. Can you show me how to do it with the coding example?

Comment: can i store those gameobjects in array and access the variables back?

Comment: Yes, you can simply do something like `myArray[0].GetComponent<blueBlock>().weight`. This would access the first element in the array, get it's blueBlock script component and then access the weight member. Do you want to store all blocks in the same array? Your question is not quite clear about that.

Comment: since i cnt find a way to do that. In a new class, i group all types of gameobjects into array using tags "players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Player");
". but then again, i donno how to access weight and other variables of the gameobjects

Comment: never use arrays in Unity, ever.  Use List<>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all blocks in one list you can create a script that has a public list and you drag all your gameobjects into the list in the inspector.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ObjectHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> theBooks;

    // You can remove by weight e.g. like this
    public void DeleteByWeight(float inputWeight)
    {
        for(int i = theBooks.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(theBooks[i].GetComponent<Book>().weight == inputWeight)
                Destroy(theBooks[i]);
                theBooks.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The script on the blocks needs to be renamed to the same name for all (`Book` in my example). From your code that is no problem since they only differ in the value of the members.

Comment: can the scripts be renamed to same name?

Comment: You can rename a class, yes. You just need to make sure you rename the file too. You would need only one of those scripts then. Set the appropriate names/types in the inspector. (You could also just create a new script and copy over.)

Comment: it wont display when i use Debug.Log(theBlocks[i].GetComponent<Block>().weight == inputWeight);

Comment: error:
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: index
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEngine.GameObject].get_Item (Int32 index) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:633)
Basket.Start () (at Assets/scripts/Basket.cs:13)

Comment: Which line is that? The destroy? This should work, I can't test it right now though. Your error means that you try to access an element of the list that doesn't exist.

Comment: i did it like this : public List<GameObject> theBlocks;
void Start()
{Debug.Log("players are"+ theBlocks[1].GetComponent<lemon>().type);
}

Comment: `theBlocks` is just the name of the list. Did you drag and drop the gameobjects into that field in the inspector?

Comment: i just realize the block size is "0". y? isnt List<GameObject> block supposed to create a list with all gameObject? or shoud i find the gameobject to add it into block?

Comment: Yes, thats one of the easiest ways to do it in unity if you have your objects already in the editor.

Comment: ok. i'll keep trying on the delete n display part. Thank you so so much

Comment: i'm sorry, but the weight is 0. i wonder y? it becomes 0 in the list class. it is a number randomly generated from another class. colour and type display just fine

Comment: Could you update your question to show the code you have now?

Comment: Well, my `theBlocks` should be `theBooks` obviously, read block instead of book. Further the order of all the `Start` functions is not set, so it might be that the start from Book.cs is called before the start of blueBook.cs (this should actually be BlueBook, all classes should start with a capital letter). Try putting the `Debug.Log` in Book into update.

Comment: the numbers are not the same, is it because it uses random.value?

Comment: You mean in the same run? If they are executed in the proper order (setting first, reading later) the values should of course be the same.

Comment: How can i ensure that they run in proper order? 
ps: its fixed now. but i'm still confused bout how to set the order

Comment: You can't or at least you better shouldn't. The order of all Start, Update etc. is varying from time to time (not the order of update being after start of course). What you actually should do is to move your weight randomizing into `Awake`.